# Unable to get roles in excel task pane (on windows 10, 1903) WebView/3.0

Tags: office-js

we are using angular in task panel and using webclient to connect webapi, before we try to get the values we will check for the roles of the user, checking the roles of the user by using context.

This was working fine on Windows 10 1809, from Windows 10 1903 we are unable to get roles of the logged in user.

we have compared the Identity of user, working and non-working. Identity is same expecting the token generate doesn't have roles in the latest OS (Windows 10, build 1903)

On further analysis found that the UserAgent on Windows 10 (Build 1903) is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; WebView/3.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

on Windows 10 (Build 1809) useragent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; WebView/3.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

Comment: Would you please share your code, I would like to validate on my side.

Comment: This is in my owinhost,when we navigate to WebApi, we see this issue

Comment: Can we have a meeting in teams, i can show you the issue

Comment: looks like an issue for webview. I would suggest that you could create an issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues. someone from webview team may help